# SQL Query Group by foreign key how please?

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-keys, key

I have two tables like this in my database:

```
Genre: Horror, Romance, Commedy, 
Film: film1, film2, film3,film4,film5,film6
```

In Film table, I have a foreign key which is connected to the primary key of Genre Table. Here is my question:

I want to get all films and group them by Genre and display in a datalist, what should the query be?

The result I want is something like:

```
Commedy: film5, film6

Horror: film1, film 2

Romance: film3, film4
```

Now I use this query:

```
Select genre,film
from Genre
inner join film on film.genrID=genre.genreID
order by genre,film ASC
```

I got this result:

```
Horror: film1

Horror: film2

Romance: film3...

...
```

I would like to group film by genre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 :

```
SELECT um.genre,
                 CONVERT(varchar(1000),  stuff(  
                          (SELECT   
                              ', ' +  film 
                              FROM tbl_Film p2  
                              WHERE p2.genreid=um.id  
                              ORDER BY film  
                              FOR XML PATH('')  
                           ) 
                           ,1,2, ''  
                       ))AS film

               FROM tbl_Film p1   
               inner join tbl_Genre um on um.id=p1.genreid   
              GROUP BY    
              um.id,um.genre
```

Comment: Thanks, Vipul Paralikar. That helps me out.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
Select genre, group_concat(film) films
    from Genre
    inner join film on film.genrID=genre.genreID
    group by Genre.genreID, genre
    order by genre,films ASC
```

Oracle:

```
Select genre, wm_concat(film) films
    from Genre
    inner join film on film.genrID=genre.genreID
    group by genrID, genre
    order by genre,films ASC
```

I do not have MS SQL Server to test, but this must work:

```
select a.genre, SUBSTRING(d.Films,1, LEN(d.Films) - 1) FilmList
from 
  (
    SELECT genrID,genre
    FROM Genre
  ) a
CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT [film] + ', ' 
    FROM (
      Select genrID,film
      from Genre
      inner join film on film.genrID=genre.genreID
    ) AS B 
    WHERE A.genrID = B.genrID 
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) D (Films)
```

Comment: Hello Reza, very sorry. I forgot to mention that that I use Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. Hence group_concat doesn't work. Any solution for MS SQL Server 2008 R2? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, as I have not worked with SQL Server, I cannot provide a complete solution. However, if you can find an equivalent of wm_concat. I will try to find it.